# Reusing iPod touch 3.1 to play music

Tags: ipod-touch

I would like to use my iPod touch 3.1 only for music, pictures and videos.  Can I still download music to this iPod from my current iPhone music list?

Answer (score 2):

You can sync music, pictures and videos to your iPod touch by syncing it with iTunes on your Mac or PC.

You can get the music that you have in your iPhone music list, by syncing the iPod with the same iTunes library that you used to sync music onto your iPhone.

Comment: Also, depending on it's age, iTunes may want to update IOS on the device. Though it is not necessary it might be a good idea to do so, from a device security standpoint.